# 'viewConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterView'. - 'FlutterView' is from 'dart:ui'

Tags: flutter

My flutter project is : [here](https://github.com/Sanmitha-Sadhishkumar/AU_Hitch_Handler). When I try to run the code present in the `Rahulraj` branch, I get the following error:

```
/C:/Users/Sanmitha/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_screenutil-5.6.1/lib/src/screen_util.dart:64:16: Error: The getter 'viewConfiguration' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterView'.
 - 'FlutterView' is from 'dart:ui'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'viewConfiguration'.
    if (window.viewConfiguration.geometry.isEmpty) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1153

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Could anyone help me to debug this issue??? Please..?

Answer (score 5):

Update: flutter_screenutil is updated, just use the actual version (5.7.0+).

= Original answer ==========================================

The issue is in the last flutter update:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121742. Property FlutterView.viewConfiguration in is removed, but it's used in flutter_screenutil library.

Possible solutions:

- rollback to any previous version of Flutter
- link this library form my fork of flutter_screenutil, where this issue is fixed (only temporary soluion!, return the dependency back as soon as flutter_screenutil will be updated):

```
  flutter_screenutil:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dmakeev/flutter_screenutil
      ref: fix-463
```

General recommendation is to use a Stable Flutter channel instead of Master.

Answer (score 1):

update flutter_screenutil library to latest version.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil/install

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring in the Latest Version(3.9.0-1.0) of Flutter (March 2023) .
The Possible Solution to this is,

1. Use Flutter Version Manager(fvm)  https://pub.dev/packages/fvm to downgrade the version of flutter in project.
   simply `flutter pub global activate fvm`

OR..
2. Remove this package flutter_screenutil and use different options like MediaQuery.

OR..
3. Downgrade flutter `flutter downgrade v1.17.0`